# Exit Sub if ActiveCell Equals a Specific Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have quite a few protected worksheets that I am trying to limit where my user can interact; however, I can't lock down the specified ranges within my code as they are input fields that intentionally impact the broader worksheet. That said, if the user ran the macro while one of the ranges were still selected then it would overwrite that specific field and throw things into disarray.

After adding the If section to my macro I have found that I can no longer successfully run the macro on ranges that I have selected within the worksheet (e.g., nothing happens)...where did I go wrong?

NOTE: I am not receiving any errors upon running the macro; however, it's also not allowing me to manipulate ranges that I have selected as intended after I added the section related to ActiveCells.

```
Sub MACRO1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    If ActiveCell = Range("F1") Or _
        ActiveCell = Range("F2") Or _
        ActiveCell = Range("F3") Or _
        ActiveCell = Range("F4") Or _
        ActiveCell = Range("F5") Or _
        ActiveCell = Range("E:E").Find("TEXT").Offset(-4, 1) Or _
        ActiveCell = Range("E:E").Find("TEXT").Offset(-3, 1) Or _
        ActiveCell = Range("E:E").Find("TEXT").Offset(-3, 1) Then
      Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Call MACRO2
    Call MACRO3

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: This way you are comparing values rather than cells. You should use: `ActiveCell.Address(0,0) = "F1"` or `ActiveCell.Address = "$F$1"` and so on.

Comment: Or try sth like this: `If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("F1:F5")) Is Nothing Then` ... (I don't understand the last three statements ...)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate both of you - @GMonet, I took your suggestion, applied it where it made sense, and adjusted the offset location to include .Address at the end to account for a dynamic range should users add or remove rows.

```
Sub MACRO1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    If ActiveCell.Address(0, 0) = "F1" Or _
        ActiveCell.Address(0, 0) = "F2" Or _
        ActiveCell.Address(0, 0) = "F3" Or _
        ActiveCell.Address(0, 0) = "F4" Or _
        ActiveCell.Address(0, 0) = "F5" Or _
        ActiveCell.Address = Range("E:E").Find("TEXT").Offset(-4, 1).Address Or _
        ActiveCell.Address = Range("E:E").Find("TEXT").Offset(-3, 1).Address Or _
        ActiveCell.Address = Range("E:E").Find("TEXT").Offset(-3, 1).Address Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Call 
    Call MACRO3

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't quite follow my idea. Should be: `ActiveCell.Address(0, 0) = "F1"` or I missed someting. Also you should not compare `Address(0,0)` with `Address`. The first represents relative address, the latter - absolute address with $. They are never equal.

Comment: @MGonet, I copied and pasted it wrong and have updated it to reflect what worked based on your suggestion - Thank you!